# How to reinstall just conda's activate command?

Tags: anaconda, conda, symlink

I have an older system which has conda 4.1.11.

In the same directory as conda (e.g. in the bin subdir of the anaconda dir) there should be the activate command.

Somehow the activate command is now a symbolic link to a different conda activate command which is a symbolic link to itself.

How can I reinstall just conda's activate command?

Comment: The `conda activate` command wasn't introduced until Conda v4.4. That older version of Conda uses `source activate`.

Comment: @merv so `activate` must still be a file right?  Where would it be located for conda 4.1.11?   I did try `source activate` & it didn't work.

Comment: Should be in the `bin/` folder. [See the repo](https://github.com/conda/conda/tree/4.1.x/bin). Note that that folder should also be on your `PATH` (which was the pre-v4.4 default).